# How do I parse a Wikiquotes response using Java?

Tags: java, android, html, json, parsing

I try to get quotes from Wikiquote by accessing it via Java.

So far I have this code:

```
 JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, "https://en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=parse&page=Ellen_DeGeneres&prop=text", null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject jobject) {
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jobject.names().length(); i++) {
                                Log.e("JSON", "key = " + jobject.names().getString(i) + " value = " + jobject.get(jobject.names().getString(i)));
                            }

                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            Log.e("JSON", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    }
                });
        request.setTag(getClass().getName());
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

This is the respones in my logcat. So it should be JSON response but the body looks quite HTML to me. So how can I parse this to get all quotes?

> key = parse value = {"title":"Ellen
>   DeGeneres","pageid":1902,"text":{"*":"\n</a>\n\n</a></div>\nEllen
>   DeGeneres</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n
>
> Ellen Lee
>   DeGeneres</a></b> (born January 26</a>, 1958</a>) is an American
>   stand-up comedienne, television hostess and actress. She starred in
>   the popular sitcom Ellen</a></i> from 1994 to 1998, and has
>   hosted her syndicated TV talk show, The Ellen
>   DeGeneres Show</a></i>, since 2003. She is married to Portia de
>   Rossi</a>.</p>\nQuotes</span>[</span>edit</a>]</span></span></h2>\n\n
>
> I
>   think the hard thing about this job [stand-up] — I mean, I think this
>   part is great — but that the traveling is y'know, 'cause — 'cause I'm
>   gone a lot from home and this time I'm out for three-and-a-half weeks
>   without going home, and that's hard, to be gone three-and-a-half weeks
>   'cause then I have to ask my friends, \"Would you mind going to the
>   house and watering the plants, and turn some lights on and make it
>   look like somebody's home, and make sure that the mobile over the crib
>   isn't tangled or the baby's gonna get bored...\"\n\n
>
> Taste
>   This</i></li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n</ul>\n\n
>
> Don't you hate when
>   people are late to work. And they always have the worst excuses. \"Oh,
>   I'm sorry I'm late, traffic.\" \"Traffic, huh? How do you think I got
>   here; helicoptered in!?\"\n\n
>
> Here and
>   Now</i></li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n</ul>\n\n
>
> I'm a — I'm a, um, a
>   godmother which is just, that's fun to be a godmother, she is
>   so</i> precious, she's the light of my life, she's two... or five
>   or something, and she's, uh... I don't know, I've never seen her — the
>   pictures are precious, she just seems so, y'know... She lives clear
>   across town, I don't have that kind of time, but, um... Well, I send
>   money and stuff, it's not like I don't have a
>   connection....\n\n
>
> Taste
>   This</i></li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n</ul>\n\n
>
> I don't want to get
>   the same looks I give people when they get on a plane holding a baby:
>   \"That's a cute baby, just keep walking, keep walking, keep going,
>   keep going....\"\n\n
>
> Taste
>   This</i></li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n</ul>\n\n
>
> If we don't want to
>   define ourselves by things as superficial as our appearances, we're
>   stuck with the revolting alternative of being judged by our actions,
>   by what we do.\n\n
>
> My Point... And I Do Have One</i>. New
>   York: Bantam Books, 1995</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n</ul>\n\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia is, first off, HTML-oriented if we can say it, and it has little sense to convert HTML to JSON (rhetorically: which JSON format by the way?), so it justs returns a portion of HTML do be displayed in an arbitrary HTML viewer. What you have to do here is:

- Make an API call to get a well-formed JSON response (you're doing it with Volley).
- Extract the quotes HTML from the JSON response.
- Extract the quotes from the HTML extracted in the previous step.
- Display the quotes somehow.

I just dumped that response as of April 5, 2017, and the following example suggests one possible solution using plain Java with org.json and [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/):

```java
public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    try ( final Reader reader = getPackageResourceReader(Q42938530.class, "wikiquotes.json") ) {
        final JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(reader);
        final JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) tokener.nextValue();
        final String quotesHtml = extractQuotesHtml(jsonObject);
        final List<String> quotes = extractQuotes(quotesHtml);
        for ( final String quote : quotes ) {
            System.out.println(quote);
        }
    }
}

private static String extractQuotesHtml(final JSONObject jsonObject) {
    return jsonObject
            .getJSONObject("parse")
            .getJSONObject("text")
            .getString("*");
}

private static List<String> extractQuotes(final String quotesHtml) {
    final Document document = Jsoup.parse(quotesHtml);
    final List<String> quotes = new ArrayList<>();
    final Elements elements = document.select("ul > li");
    for ( final Element element : elements ) {
        quotes.add(element.text());
    }
    return quotes;
}
```

Of course, you have to fine-tune the `extractQuotes` method to extract the quotes more accurately. Currently the example above is able to produce the following output to stdout:

> I think the hard thing about this job [stand-up] — I mean, I think this part is great — but that the traveling is y'know, 'cause — 'cause I'm gone a lot from home and this time I'm out for three-and-a-half weeks without going home, and that's hard, to be gone three-and-a-half weeks 'cause then I have to ask my friends, "Would you mind going to the house and watering the plants, and turn some lights on and make it look like somebody's home, and make sure that the mobile over the crib isn't tangled or the baby's gonna get bored..." Taste This
>   Taste This
>   Don't you hate when people are late to work. And they always have the worst excuses. "Oh, I'm sorry I'm late, traffic." "Traffic, huh? How do you think I got here; helicoptered in!?" Here and Now
>   Here and Now